# XML with MFC++ not getting all of the file

Tags: xml, node.js, visual-studio-2010, mfc, msxml

I am trying to read xml file with `MFC++` using `MSXML 6.0`. I am trying to read the xml file as follows but the `BSTR` variable with the file information does not have full information. I tried with extracting node information depending on node name but its also not returning any value. Please have a look and check why is it not returning any value at all. Thank you.

```
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        IXMLDOMDocument *pXMLDom=NULL;
        IXMLDOMParseError *pXMLErr = NULL;
        BSTR bstrXML = NULL;
        BSTR bstrErr = NULL;
        BSTR strFindText = NULL;
        VARIANT_BOOL varStatus;
        VARIANT varFileName;
        VariantInit(&varFileName);

        CString nodex;
        nodex.Format("maxWeakCount");

        strFindText = nodex.AllocSysString();

        CHK_HR(CreateAndInitDOM(&pXMLDom));

        int check = 0;
        while (check <= stage_value)
        {
            // XML file name to load
            CString file_name;
            file_name.Format("stage%d.xml",check);
            LPCWSTR pstr;

            pstr = file_name.AllocSysString();
            //string val = file_name.str();

            IXMLDOMNodeList **NodeListPtr = NULL;
            CHK_HR(VariantFromString(pstr, varFileName));
            CHK_HR(pXMLDom->load(varFileName, &varStatus));

            if (varStatus == VARIANT_TRUE)
            {
                //CHK_HR(pXMLDom->get_xml(&bstrXML));
                pXMLDom->get_xml(&bstrXML);
                printf("XML DOM loaded from stocks.xml:\n%S\n", bstrXML);
                TRACE(bstrXML);

                pXMLDom->selectNodes(strFindText,NodeListPtr);
                //pXMLDom->getElementsByTagName(strFindText,NodeListPtr);

            }
            else
            {
                // Failed to load xml, get last parsing error
                CHK_HR(pXMLDom->get_parseError(&pXMLErr));
                CHK_HR(pXMLErr->get_reason(&bstrErr));
                printf("Failed to load DOM from stocks.xml. %S\n", bstrErr);
            }
            check++;
        }

        CleanUp:
            SAFE_RELEASE(pXMLDom);
            SAFE_RELEASE(pXMLErr);
            SysFreeString(bstrXML);
            SysFreeString(bstrErr);
            VariantClear(&varFileName);
```

**XML file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<opencv_storage>


-<stage0>

<maxWeakCount>24</maxWeakCount>

<stageThreshold>-6.7922687530517578e-001</stageThreshold>


-<weakClassifiers>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 5222 -7.4742577970027924e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 7.8248846530914307e-001 -3.9459058642387390e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 145821 4.2300157248973846e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -2.2594805061817169e-001 7.2615057229995728e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 62933 -3.3906875178217888e-003</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 3.2157972455024719e-001 -4.7761633992195129e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 117865 -5.8019475545734167e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -7.1146464347839355e-001 1.9676868617534637e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 120902 6.5625971183180809e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 1.5879715979099274e-001 -7.6414048671722412e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 120902 -4.4437538599595428e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -6.7004400491714478e-001 2.0068950951099396e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 143302 -1.8973767757415771e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 5.9475421905517578e-001 -2.5145307183265686e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 2425 1.6013659536838531e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -1.8447668850421906e-001 6.7021727561950684e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 96406 9.1860461980104446e-003</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -3.2802325487136841e-001 3.7773028016090393e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 35514 -2.6462525129318237e-003</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -7.1718478202819824e-001 1.8943628668785095e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 13247 -3.8060642778873444e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 4.9289038777351379e-001 -2.6732766628265381e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 127620 -2.4896641261875629e-003</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -8.2117795944213867e-001 1.5855802595615387e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 146216 -1.7213714309036732e-003</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -6.9493049383163452e-001 1.1804508417844772e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 49725 -1.0400196537375450e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 5.7870316505432129e-001 -2.0522624254226685e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 3449 -5.6679256260395050e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 5.8843207359313965e-001 -1.8752425909042358e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 33303 -2.1169674582779408e-003</internalNodes>

<leafValues> -6.7556095123291016e-001 1.7081934213638306e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 98086 8.1965804565697908e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 1.3254085183143616e-001 -7.5527042150497437e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 97891 4.8866466386243701e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 1.7491920292377472e-001 -5.5380541086196899e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 98268 8.6379586718976498e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 1.6863669455051422e-001 -6.6373646259307861e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 141194 -7.2060570120811462e-002</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 8.7314307689666748e-001 -1.5330317616462708e-001</leafValues>

</_>


-<_>

<internalNodes> 0 -1 23622 5.1324046216905117e-004</internalNodes>

<leafValues> 2.3784525692462921e-001 -5.3238695859909058e-001</leafValues>

</_>


</weakClassifiers>

</stage0>

</opencv_storage>
```

I am trying to read this file using MSXML and process it further by extracting information of every node but node lis is returning as a bad pointer.

Comment: _the BSTR variable with the file information does not have full information_. - What does this mean?

Comment: Its not showing me the whole xml file but just some starting part of it.

Comment: Hi, do you still have an issue?

Comment: yep but i stopped reading it and break it down in smaller file.. :x